# Raspberry pi Opencv being slow

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm using RPI for Color Hue Image Processing, For this purpose i have to convert the image format from BGR to HSV by:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Normally this will take 8 ms on 704*704 resolution; to make it faster i divide the image to two segments and process each segment on a separate thread to speed up the BGR2HSV conversion:

```
num_processes = 2
c = 0
hsv = np.zeros((704,704,3))
frame = vs.read()

def bgrhsv(x):
    global c
    hsv[int(frame.shape[0]/num_processes*x):int(frame.shape[0]/num_processes*(x+1)), :] = cv2.cvtColor(frame[int(frame.shape[0]/num_processes*x):int(frame.shape[0]/num_processes*(x+1)), :], cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    c += 1

e1 = time.time()
Thread(target=bgrhsv, args=(0,)).start()
Thread(target=bgrhsv, args=(1,)).start()
while c < 2:
    pass
e2 = time.time()
```

But, this way the conversion process will take up to 20 ms!

How can i make the BGR2HSV conversion faster?

Comment: As you mentioned using a divide and conquer strategy with multiple threads may improve your performance but I do not see very much there (prove me wrong). I suggest reading smaller images.

Comment: What happens if you start just one thread, by the way?

Comment: I don't know Python well enough but have you divided the image into 2 halves the same way as Python lays out 2D structures in memory? If you have divided the wrong dimension you will get lots of cache misses. If you currently split left and right halves to your 2 threads, try splitting top and bottom halves, and vice versa.

Comment: Is `pass` a good thing to do in a loop? What happens if you yield the CPU instead with `time.sleep(0))` ?